# CSS specificity for link styles

Tags: html, css

Consider the following

```css
.pr a { color: green; }
a:link { color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="pr">
    Welcome, please <a href="#">login</a>
</p>
```

On what rule does the above code follow such that the link gets the red color?

From the style resolution
[image]

From the above code

- Both are author styles i.e same origin
- None is !important
- None is inline
- Selector specificity (Here)

I used number of `(id's, classes, tags)` notation

`.pr a` -> (0,1,1)

`a:link` -> (0,0,1)

So from my understanding `.pr a` should have won. What am i getting wrong?

Comment: You may know them, but what do you understand about them? Which one of these is author and/or user-agent? How do the specificity values add up? Saying you know them doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Re edit: Read the selector specificity rules again (they are in the accepted answer of the duplicate). id selectors, class selectors and type selectors are not the only things scored.

Comment: Edited @BoltClock

Comment: _"So from my understanding `.pr a` should have won. What am i getting wrong?"_ It did win, the link is green

Comment: The link is red @j08691

Comment: @Emmanuel Mtali: Does the duplicate link answer your question? If it's not terribly clear I can reopen.

Comment: @j08691: No it's not.

Comment: @BoltClock The link is green for me. Latest Chrome Win10. https://i.ibb.co/Kyss5Kk/Screenshot-2021-04-06-095153.png

Comment: Try opening the question in incognito window @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `:link` pseudo-class — that carries equal specificity with class selectors. So the two selectors are equally specific at (0, 1, 1), and `a:link` wins because it comes later in the CSS source order.

However should you click the link and cause it to be visited, the `:link` pseudo will no longer match altogether, leaving `.pr a` the only rule to apply and turning the link green.

Comment: I think something is going on here. The rule that :link has equal specificity with class selector holds as long as the link is not visited, after the link has been visited :link promoted to a lower priority and .pr a wins

Comment: @Emmanuel Mtali: Yeah, visiting the link would be the only way to reproduce it. But that requires interacting with the snippet. You can't reproduce the behavior just by running it and leaving it alone. You think j08691 might have clicked on the link by accident while viewing the snippet?

Comment: The browser in non-incognito remembers so j08691 might have visited the link in he past

Comment: @Emmanuel Mtali: Hmm, fair enough. I must admit I haven't paid attention to how visited # links work within the snippet iframe.

Comment: So why do you think rules change after visiting a link?

Comment: @Emmanuel Mtali: You were pretty close, but it's not that :link's priority is reduced but that it stops matching entirely. The entire color: red rule stops applying.